# To use the internet of my phone for PC

Tags: android-pc, usb-modem

I have a Smartphone with cellular internet and I tried to use this internet with a PC, with a USB cable, as I made in the past with a cell phone.

It doesn't work: Not in Ubuntu 16.04, nor in window 7.
Someone can give me a good advice?

My phone is a GINI e6 (e 6_0301_V5765); Android 5.1

Comment: What phone is it? Menton the model name... Also check this: [USB Tethering](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb+tethering)

Comment: e 6_0301_V5765    @Gokul NC

Comment: @GokulNC the USB Terhering doesn't work with my phone

Comment: @kouty Try the wireless hotspot.

Comment: @Fiksdal you are right, now it works, the problem was that the USB connection was not detected, I get it out and entered it again and it works.

Comment: @kouty Wireless works or USB works?

Comment: @Fiksdal USB, at init I made hotspot only and not worked, I added USB and it works. I see that usb only also works

Comment: @kouty I don't know what you're trying to say, but I'm glad it worked.

Comment: @Fiksdal at and USB alone the way which worked

Comment: @kouty Alright.